# How do you typedef a function pointer type with parameter pack arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers, variadic-templates

What's the syntax to typdef a parameter pack into a function pointer?

I want to be able to typedef a function pointer, but the compiler complains when I do something like this

```
template< class ...Args >
struct method { typedef typename void(*type)(void*, Args...); };
```

with a message along the lines of `error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'void'`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: Shit, sorry guys. I misread an error from my compiler that said `error: need 'typename' before ...` but I put it there in the struct instead of the reference to the dependent type :/

Answer (score 2):

It works fine without `typename`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64b3fbec9276dd70

You shouldn't use `typename` here because there is no *nested-name-specifier*.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you should remove `typename` from the `typedef` line

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct method
 { typedef void(*type)(void*, Args...); };
```

Another solution could be using `using` instead of `typedef` (IMHO is a little clearer)

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct method
 { using type = void(*)(void*, Args...); };
```